# Keeping style applied using :hover until transition complete?

Tags: css, z-index, css-transitions

I have a bunch of tiles on a page that expand as the user mouses over them. The expanded one should have the highest `z-index`, and this works, but I need the z-index to remain until the size transition is complete. Is there a way to do this using CSS only, *no JavaScript*? Since I'm using transitions, I'm not too worried about compatibility here, I applied progressive enhancement correctly.

[Here's a jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uHJwT/) that demonstrates this. Mouse over A; it transitions out. Mouse off of it, however, and it falls behind B. I need it to stay in front of B until the transition completes. Is there an elegant way to do this?

Comment: @MademoiselleGeek: Now linked to jsFiddle. :P

Comment: @minitech, obvious thing that come to my mind was to animate the z-index as well as. z-index is animatable property but unfortunately that doesn't seem to work.

Comment: @VinayC: I could get it to work, but the problem there is that it requires precisely calculated values for `z-index`, something that won't be easy to do. I'd rather use JavaScript if that's the only solution...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to define the `z-index`, as well as animate it.

[This](http://jsfiddle.net/A83vN/) works in Firefox (8.0.1) and Webkit.

Answer (score 2):

You need to set `z-index` to transition too: http://jsfiddle.net/uHJwT/2/

Comment: Um... did you *try* that? It doesn't work. The behaviour is identical.

Comment: This was the first thing that I had tried but doesn't seem to work in FF!

Comment: @VinayC: It turns out that FF needs a `z-index` to transition *from*.

Answer (score 1):

Try using transitions like in http://jsfiddle.net/frozenkoi/YK52N/ (note the comments in the CSS section, for both the `.item` and `.item:hover`)

The trick is to use transitions for the `z-index` property too. You can set, for example, a value of 10 for the normal items and 11 for the hovered ones. You also have to use `transition-delay` so that the animation for moving the mouse out doesn't reset the `z-index` inmediately. Next, add a different value to `transition-delay` to the rule for `:hover` with a value of zero so that the `z-index` does update inmediately when the mouse goes into the item.

In short, `.item` has the transition for mouse out of the item and `.item:hover` the rules for when the mouse moves in.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the one solution: http://jsfiddle.net/uHJwT/4/

Essentially, it uses another wrapper div that has sufficient width & height to cover animated surface - on hover, it elevates its z-index so that the animated div remains on top. Of course, this is not full-proof solution - it is based on the fact that typical hover off would be down movement and it works for that - but hover off in diagonal direction would not work. But seems to be a reasonable CSS only solution - I would rather used js to get a perfect one.