# CSS: Preventing a property to affect on element until the end of transition

Tags: css, css-transitions, z-index

We've some boxes to show some data on hover. So, when we move mouse over one element, it should expand, get in front of other elements, and show the hidden data.

I did something like this:

```
box:hover {
    z-index: 50;
}
```

But there's one problem; When we move mouse on another outer white space, the `z-index` back to the value, same as others. So it's visible that hovered element is in lower layer than next one.

**How to prevent a property to apply, until the end of transition?**

Here's my [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ypw1zxhr/). Try to hover on one element, move your mouse out of element and the background-image of other elements will be in front of our hovered element before the transition ends.

Update: this is the screen shot of problem. This is when we unhover on element. `background-image` of another elements come in front of our hovered element.

[image: Our problem! Check the jsFiddle link above]

Comment: It may be an artifact of my browser (Safari Mac), but I don't get the issue you describe. However, with Chrome, I get a red background, so I suspect the CSS may be wonky.

Comment: @MAGNAWS Added screen shot to describe better the situation

Comment: That doesn't happen on my browsers (Safari, Chrome or Firefox on Mac). However, Safari displays the main box background as white. I suspect that the CSS is broken. By "broken" I don't necessarily mean "wrong." It may be in an undefined area; where different browsers react differently. What I usually do in these cases, is try to refactor into the simplest form possible; sometimes giving up some fancy in the process (It is a nice effect, BTW).

Comment: @MAGNAWS Thanks for your complimentary words. I tested it by chrome ( v43 ) on Macbook ( mac OSX mavericks ) and it still has problem! I think you're moving your mouse on title to unhover item, and it's still the `.box` area, so it works correctly. Try to move your mouse out of the box by moving to cursor to the left side or right side, and the bug is parading.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Keeping style applied using :hover until transition complete?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8264858/keeping-style-applied-using-hover-until-transition-complete)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a transition also for `z-index`, but insert a delay only when `.box` is in normal state.

Doing so the `z-index` will change istantly on hover, while on the opposite action (“unhover”) the `z-index` will take its initial value but only after `0.5` seconds (the duration of your expanding effect is `0.4` seconds)

```
.box {
   ...
   z-index: 1;
   -webkit-transition: z-index 0s .5s;   
      -moz-transition: z-index 0s .5s;   
           transition: z-index 0s .5s;   
}

.box:hover {
    -webkit-transition: z-index 0s 0s;
       -moz-transition: z-index 0s 0s;   
            transition: z-index 0s 0s; 
    z-index: 50;
}
```

example: http://jsfiddle.net/yjg2oach/

Comment: Your edited fiddle ( the second one ) works perfect in chrome, but on firefox, it fails :(

Comment: @mrReiha that's because an initial z-index value is missing from .box (and depending on the version of firefox, a `-moz-` prefix may be also necessary)

Comment: Wow, Sounds amazing. I didn't know `z-index` is animatable. Thanks a lot.

Comment: in fact it is not animatable. You're just delaying the reset of its value

Comment: It's not animatable literally, but according to the specs definition of animatable, it is. http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-transitions/ ( Check 7.1 section ). Thanks a lot, I learned something new today ;)

Answer (score 1):

Add a transition attribute to your `.box` group.

```
.box {
    float: left;
    position: relative;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    margin: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 35px;
        transition: .4s;
}
```

Fixed [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ypw1zxhr/1/)

Comment: It works perfect on chrome, but on firefox, it still has problem :(